# make useEffect fire before render JSX part

Tags: react-native, use-effect

I have a functional component in an expo react native app as in code below. The trouble I'm having is that the `render part` i.e. where JSX appears executes before the code inside `useEffect`.

I wanted to execute the render part after the useEffect part so that the screen doesn't flicker due to UnAuthenticatedNavigator showing first and then after a second or so when useEffect executes the other component of AuthenticatedNavigator shows.

**Question** : How can I make sure that `render part` executes after the `useEffect` part in App component below?

*App.js*

```
  const App = () => {
  
  const [user, setUser] = useState();//user is user related data including userToken, companyId, email, fullName
  
  const getUserData = async () => {
    try {
      const userData = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@userData');

      if (userData !== null) {
        setUser(JSON.parse(userData));
      }

    } catch (e) {
      alert("Sorry! An unexpected error has occurred while reading user data.");
    }
  };

  const setUserData = async (userData) => {
    try {

       if (userData) {
        const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(userData);
        await AsyncStorage.setItem("@userData", jsonValue);
        setUser(value);//change state so re-rendering happens
      } 

    } catch (e) {
      alert("Sorry! An unexpected error has occurred while saving user data.");
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getUserData();//this executes after the render part. I would like it to execute before the render part
  }, []);


  //render part as below. user is still undefined initially since useEffect part executes after this render part.
  return (
    (user ? <AuthenticatedNavigator /> : <UnAuthenticatedNavigator />)
  );
};
```

Comment: Did you try using `useLayoutEffect`?

Comment: No. Should I just replace useEffect with useLayoutEffect? Anyways I'll look into it and see if it solves my issue.

Comment: I tried it but `useLayoutEffect` seems to still cause flickering as was happening with `useEffect`.

Comment: May be best solution here is to use a class based App component if I want `render part` to execute after the `componentDidMount` part so no flickering happens.

Comment: Why not have a loading flag and show an activityindicator until the user is loaded ?

Comment: @Guruparan Giritharan, you mean  loading flag is an App scoped variable or part of component state?

Comment: You can check my answer, it would be state variable for the component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The screen would render at least once, so you can use this pattern to show a loading using ActivityIndicator until the user is loaded.

```
const App = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(); //user is user related data including userToken, companyId, email, fullName
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const getUserData = async () => {
    try {
      const userData = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@userData');

      if (userData !== null) {
        setUser(JSON.parse(userData));
      }
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (e) {
      alert('Sorry! An unexpected error has occurred while reading user data.');
    }
  };

  const setUserData = async (userData) => {
    try {
      if (userData) {
        const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(userData);
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('@userData', jsonValue);
        setUser(value); //change state so re-rendering happens
      }
    } catch (e) {
      alert('Sorry! An unexpected error has occurred while saving user data.');
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getUserData(); //this executes after the render part. I would like it to execute before the render part
  }, []);

  if (loading) return <ActivityIndicator />;

  //render part as below. user is still undefined initially since useEffect part executes after this render part.
  return user ? <AuthenticatedNavigator /> : <UnAuthenticatedNavigator />;
};
```

Comment: I tried your code but I'm getting the ActivityIndicator showing always i.e. the line of code `setLoading(false)` never gets executed.

Comment: Can you debug n see whether you set the loading ? I set it to false in getUserData function

Comment: Yes, it was my mistake. I put that line of code just after setUser when it should be outside the `if (userData !== null)`. Thanks for your help. Is it possible to show the activity indicator for atleast 2 seconds?

Comment: Then you will have to put some sort of timeout and handle that there is no timing for activity indicator

Comment: You mean the setLoading should called after a delay using a setTimeout. I'll try that.

Comment: Yes something like that should work, as long as the loading is true it would be displayed once you toggle it your actual views would render

Comment: I replaced setLoading with following and it displayed activityindicator for 10 seconds: `setTimeout( function() { setLoading(false); }.bind(this), 10000)`.